# MediaPlayer And SeekBar On Android ( Grow Heap )

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, seekbar

After 20 seconds of playing the song the Activity will close..

I've got this picture of that error from Logcat ( Green line )

[image]

I think there's problem with memory but i couldn't catch it !

I tested it on Sony Xperia P and Samsung Galaxy S3 and same problem happens everytime

I tried to find solution for this problem for 1 week .. but there's no way to fix it

For record : When I remove these lines

```
endTime.setText(String.valueOf(milliSecondsToTimer(mp.getDuration())));
currentTime.setText(String.valueOf(milliSecondsToTimer(mp.getCurrentPosition())));
```

Everything seems ok ..

Activity Code:

```
package com.blurcode.enrique2013;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class Music extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener,   SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener  {

private ListView list_music;
private static MediaPlayer mp =null;
private static SeekBar seek = null;

private static TextView currentTime;
private static TextView endTime;

private ImageView Play;
private static ImageView Forward;
private static ImageView Backward;
private static ImageView Next;
private static ImageView Previous;

ArrayList<String> Parts;
private Timer myTimer1;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.music);
    Init();
    //SeekLoad();

    myTimer1 = new Timer();
    myTimer1.schedule(new TimerTask() 
    {
        public void run()
        {
            UpdateProgressBar();
        }
    },100, 100);

    Init_list();

    MediaClicks();

}

void Init(){
    seek = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seek);
    currentTime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.currentTime);
    endTime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.endTime);

    Play = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.player_play);
    Forward = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.player_forward);
    Backward = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.player_backward);
    Next = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.player_next);
    Previous = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.player_back);


    if(mp != null){
        if(!mp.isPlaying())
            Play.setImageResource(R.drawable.player_play);
        else
            Play.setImageResource(R.drawable.player_pause);
    }else{
        Play.setImageResource(R.drawable.player_play);
    }


}

void MediaClicks(){
    Play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try{
                if(mp != null){
                    if(mp.isPlaying()){
                        mp.pause();
                        Play.setImageResource(R.drawable.player_play);
                    }else{
                        mp.start();
                        Play.setImageResource(R.drawable.player_pause);
                    }
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Select one music from the list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }catch(Exception ex){Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.getMessage(), 500).show();}
        }
    });

    Forward.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
            if(currentPosition + 5000 <= mp.getDuration()){
                mp.seekTo(currentPosition + 5000);
            }else{
                mp.seekTo(mp.getDuration());
            }
        }
    });

    Backward.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
            if(currentPosition - 5000 >= 0){
                mp.seekTo(currentPosition - 5000);
            }else{
                mp.seekTo(0);
            }
        }
    });

    Next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    Previous.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
}

void SeekLoad(){
    seek.setProgress(0);
    seek.setMax(mp.getDuration());
}

void PlayNow(String url){
    try{
        mp = new MediaPlayer();

        seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); // Important
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(this); // Important

        mp.reset();
        mp.setDataSource(url);
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                Play.setImageResource(R.drawable.player_play);
            }
        });
        SeekLoad();



    }catch(Exception ex){Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
}

public void UpdateProgressBar() {
    this.runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick1);
}  

// Milliseconds To Time
public String milliSecondsToTimer(long milliseconds){
    String finalTimerString = "";
    String secondsString = "";

    int hours = (int)( milliseconds / (1000*60*60));
    int minutes = (int)(milliseconds % (1000*60*60)) / (1000*60);
    int seconds = (int) ((milliseconds % (1000*60*60)) % (1000*60) / 1000);
    if(hours > 0){
        finalTimerString = hours + ":";
    }

    if(seconds < 10){
        secondsString = "0" + seconds;
    }else{
        secondsString = "" + seconds;}

    finalTimerString = finalTimerString + minutes + ":" + secondsString;
    return finalTimerString;
}

public int getProgressPercentage(long currentDuration, long totalDuration){
    Double percentage = (double) 0;

    long currentSeconds = (int) (currentDuration / 1000);
    long totalSeconds = (int) (totalDuration / 1000);

    percentage =(((double)currentSeconds)/totalSeconds)*100;

    return percentage.intValue();
}


private Runnable Timer_Tick1 = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){ 
        try{
            endTime.setText(String.valueOf(milliSecondsToTimer(mp.getDuration())));
            currentTime.setText(String.valueOf(milliSecondsToTimer(mp.getCurrentPosition())));
            seek.setProgress(mp.getCurrentPosition());
            //int progress = (int)(getProgressPercentage(mp.getCurrentPosition(), mp.getDuration()));
        }catch (Exception ex) {} 
    }
};


void Init_list(){
    list_music = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_music);
    Parts = new ArrayList<String>();
    Parts.add("First Song");
    Parts.add("Second Song");
    Parts.add("Third Song");
    Parts.add("Fourth Song");
    Parts.add("Fifth Song");
    Parts.add("Sixth Song");
    Parts.add("First Song");
    Parts.add("First Song");
    Parts.add("First Song");
    Parts.add("First Song");
    Parts.add("First Song");

    ListAdapterSimple adapter = new ListAdapterSimple(Parts,getApplicationContext());
    list_music.setAdapter(adapter);
    list_music.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            if(checkInternetConnection()){
                //arg2
                switch(arg2){
                case 0:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "buffering..", 600).show();
                    PlayNow("http://server11.mp3quran.net/shatri/002.mp3");
                    Music.this.Play.setImageResource(R.drawable.player_pause);
                    /*
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {
                            PlayNow("http://server11.mp3quran.net/shatri/002.mp3");
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    Music.this.Play.setImageResource(R.drawable.player_pause);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }).start();*/

                    break;

                }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Check your Internet connection please", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

public  boolean checkInternetConnection(){
    boolean isFound;
    ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
            && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
            && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) 
    {

        isFound=true;
    } else 
    {
        isFound= false;
    }
    return isFound;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.music, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}}
```

Logcat Outputs:

```
11-27 16:55:12.296: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:12.296: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:12.296: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 12805 (msec)
11-27 16:55:12.296: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 12805 (msec)
11-27 16:55:12.456: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:12.456: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:12.461: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 12991 (msec)
11-27 16:55:12.461: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 12991 (msec)
11-27 16:55:12.616: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:12.616: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:12.616: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 13177 (msec)
11-27 16:55:12.616: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 13177 (msec)
11-27 16:55:12.621: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:12.626: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:12.626: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 13177 (msec)
11-27 16:55:12.626: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 13177 (msec)
11-27 16:55:12.666: V/MediaPlayer(8356): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
11-27 16:55:12.666: V/MediaPlayer(8356): buffering 0
11-27 16:55:12.666: V/MediaPlayer(8356): callback application
11-27 16:55:12.666: V/MediaPlayer(8356): back from callback
11-27 16:55:12.751: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:12.751: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:12.756: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 13363 (msec)
11-27 16:55:12.756: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 13363 (msec)
11-27 16:55:12.906: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:12.906: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:12.906: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 13548 (msec)
11-27 16:55:12.906: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 13548 (msec)
11-27 16:55:12.906: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:12.906: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:12.906: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 13548 (msec)
11-27 16:55:12.906: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 13548 (msec)
11-27 16:55:13.061: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:13.061: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:13.066: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 13548 (msec)
11-27 16:55:13.066: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 13548 (msec)
11-27 16:55:13.226: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:13.226: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:13.231: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 13734 (msec)
11-27 16:55:13.231: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 13734 (msec)
11-27 16:55:13.231: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:13.231: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:13.231: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 13734 (msec)
11-27 16:55:13.231: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 13734 (msec)
11-27 16:55:13.386: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:13.386: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:13.386: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 13920 (msec)
11-27 16:55:13.386: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 13920 (msec)
11-27 16:55:13.386: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:13.386: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:13.391: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 13920 (msec)
11-27 16:55:13.391: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 13920 (msec)
11-27 16:55:13.546: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:13.546: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:13.546: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 14106 (msec)
11-27 16:55:13.546: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 14106 (msec)
11-27 16:55:13.666: V/MediaPlayer(8356): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
11-27 16:55:13.666: V/MediaPlayer(8356): buffering 0
11-27 16:55:13.666: V/MediaPlayer(8356): callback application
11-27 16:55:13.666: V/MediaPlayer(8356): back from callback
11-27 16:55:13.686: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:13.686: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:13.691: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 14291 (msec)
11-27 16:55:13.691: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 14291 (msec)
11-27 16:55:13.691: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:13.691: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:13.691: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 14291 (msec)
11-27 16:55:13.691: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 14291 (msec)
11-27 16:55:13.841: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:13.841: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:13.846: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 14477 (msec)
11-27 16:55:13.846: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 14477 (msec)
11-27 16:55:13.981: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:13.981: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:13.981: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 14477 (msec)
11-27 16:55:13.981: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 14477 (msec)
11-27 16:55:14.131: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:14.131: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:14.131: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 14663 (msec)
11-27 16:55:14.131: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 14663 (msec)
11-27 16:55:14.131: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:14.131: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:14.131: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 14663 (msec)
11-27 16:55:14.131: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 14663 (msec)
11-27 16:55:14.301: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:14.301: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:14.306: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 14849 (msec)
11-27 16:55:14.306: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 14849 (msec)
11-27 16:55:14.306: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:14.306: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:14.306: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 14849 (msec)
11-27 16:55:14.306: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 14849 (msec)
11-27 16:55:14.441: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:14.441: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:14.441: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 15035 (msec)
11-27 16:55:14.441: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 15035 (msec)
11-27 16:55:14.576: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:14.576: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:14.576: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 15220 (msec)
11-27 16:55:14.576: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 15220 (msec)
11-27 16:55:14.666: V/MediaPlayer(8356): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
11-27 16:55:14.666: V/MediaPlayer(8356): buffering 0
11-27 16:55:14.666: V/MediaPlayer(8356): callback application
11-27 16:55:14.666: V/MediaPlayer(8356): back from callback
11-27 16:55:14.721: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:14.721: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:14.726: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 15220 (msec)
11-27 16:55:14.726: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 15220 (msec)
11-27 16:55:14.726: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:14.726: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:14.726: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 15220 (msec)
11-27 16:55:14.726: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 15220 (msec)
11-27 16:55:14.881: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:14.881: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:14.881: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 15406 (msec)
11-27 16:55:14.881: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 15406 (msec)
11-27 16:55:15.031: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:15.031: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:15.031: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 15592 (msec)
11-27 16:55:15.031: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 15592 (msec)
11-27 16:55:15.031: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:15.031: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:15.036: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 15592 (msec)
11-27 16:55:15.036: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 15592 (msec)
11-27 16:55:15.166: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:15.166: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:15.166: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 15778 (msec)
11-27 16:55:15.171: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 15778 (msec)
11-27 16:55:15.296: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:15.296: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:15.296: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 15778 (msec)
11-27 16:55:15.296: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 15778 (msec)
11-27 16:55:15.296: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:15.296: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:15.296: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 15778 (msec)
11-27 16:55:15.296: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 15778 (msec)
11-27 16:55:15.416: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:15.416: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:15.421: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 15963 (msec)
11-27 16:55:15.421: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 15963 (msec)
11-27 16:55:15.551: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:15.551: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:15.556: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 16149 (msec)
11-27 16:55:15.556: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 16149 (msec)
11-27 16:55:15.666: V/MediaPlayer(8356): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
11-27 16:55:15.666: V/MediaPlayer(8356): buffering 0
11-27 16:55:15.666: V/MediaPlayer(8356): callback application
11-27 16:55:15.666: V/MediaPlayer(8356): back from callback
11-27 16:55:15.716: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:15.716: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:15.716: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 16335 (msec)
11-27 16:55:15.716: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 16335 (msec)
11-27 16:55:15.716: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:15.716: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:15.716: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 16335 (msec)
11-27 16:55:15.716: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 16335 (msec)
11-27 16:55:15.846: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:15.846: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:15.846: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 16335 (msec)
11-27 16:55:15.846: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 16335 (msec)
11-27 16:55:16.006: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:16.006: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:16.006: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 16521 (msec)
11-27 16:55:16.006: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 16521 (msec)
11-27 16:55:16.006: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:16.006: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:16.006: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 16521 (msec)
11-27 16:55:16.006: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 16521 (msec)
11-27 16:55:16.211: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:16.211: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:16.211: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 16706 (msec)
11-27 16:55:16.211: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 16706 (msec)
11-27 16:55:16.211: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:16.211: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:16.211: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 16706 (msec)
11-27 16:55:16.211: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 16706 (msec)
11-27 16:55:16.396: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:16.396: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:16.401: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 16892 (msec)
11-27 16:55:16.401: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 16892 (msec)
11-27 16:55:16.401: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:16.401: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:16.401: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 16892 (msec)
11-27 16:55:16.401: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 16892 (msec)
11-27 16:55:16.591: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:16.591: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:16.591: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 17078 (msec)
11-27 16:55:16.591: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 17078 (msec)
11-27 16:55:16.666: V/MediaPlayer(8356): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
11-27 16:55:16.666: V/MediaPlayer(8356): buffering 0
11-27 16:55:16.666: V/MediaPlayer(8356): callback application
11-27 16:55:16.666: V/MediaPlayer(8356): back from callback
11-27 16:55:16.761: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:16.761: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:16.761: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 17264 (msec)
11-27 16:55:16.761: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 17264 (msec)
11-27 16:55:16.766: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:16.766: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:16.766: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 17264 (msec)
11-27 16:55:16.766: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 17264 (msec)
11-27 16:55:16.951: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:16.951: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:16.951: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 17449 (msec)
11-27 16:55:16.951: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 17449 (msec)
11-27 16:55:16.956: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:16.956: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:16.956: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 17449 (msec)
11-27 16:55:16.956: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 17449 (msec)
11-27 16:55:17.106: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:17.106: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:17.111: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 17635 (msec)
11-27 16:55:17.111: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 17635 (msec)
11-27 16:55:17.111: V/MediaPlayer(8356): getDuration
11-27 16:55:17.111: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getDuration: 7084625 (msec)
11-27 16:55:17.111: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 17635 (msec)
11-27 16:55:17.111: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(8356): getCurrentPosition: 17635 (msec)
11-27 16:55:18.036: D/dalvikvm(10335): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 42K, 6% free 12160K/12931K, paused 21ms, total 21ms
11-27 16:55:18.041: I/dalvikvm-heap(10335): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.684MB for 1310416-byte allocation
11-27 16:55:18.066: D/dalvikvm(10335): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 6% free 13438K/14215K, paused 12ms+2ms, total 24ms
11-27 16:55:18.081: D/dalvikvm(10335): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 6% free 13438K/14215K, paused 11ms, total 11ms
11-27 16:55:18.091: I/dalvikvm-heap(10335): Grow heap (frag case) to 15.905MB for 2329616-byte allocation
11-27 16:55:18.111: D/dalvikvm(10335): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 5% free 15713K/16519K, paused 12ms+2ms, total 23ms
11-27 16:55:18.111: D/dalvikvm(10335): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 4ms
11-27 16:55:18.161: D/dalvikvm(10335): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1637K, 15% free 15079K/17543K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
11-27 16:55:18.186: D/dalvikvm(10335): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 9% free 16070K/17543K, paused 3ms+1ms, total 14ms
11-27 16:55:18.186: D/dalvikvm(10335): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 9ms
11-27 16:55:18.211: D/dalvikvm(10335): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 356K, 9% free 16038K/17543K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
11-27 16:55:18.211: I/dalvikvm-heap(10335): Grow heap (frag case) to 16.786MB for 590800-byte allocation
11-27 16:55:18.231: D/dalvikvm(10335): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 9% free 16615K/18183K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
11-27 16:55:18.251: D/dalvikvm(10335): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 324K, 9% free 16619K/18183K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
11-27 16:55:18.281: D/dalvikvm(10335): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 326K, 8% free 17196K/18567K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
11-27 16:55:18.351: D/libEGL(10335): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
11-27 16:55:18.366: D/libEGL(10335): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
11-27 16:55:18.366: D/libEGL(10335): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
11-27 16:55:18.371: D/(10335): Device driver API match
11-27 16:55:18.371: D/(10335): Device driver API version: 10
11-27 16:55:18.371: D/(10335): User space API version: 10 
11-27 16:55:18.371: D/(10335): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Tue Oct 16 15:37:13 KST 2012 
11-27 16:55:18.411: D/OpenGLRenderer(10335): Enabling debug mode 0
```

Comment: Can you please post your full stacktrace

Comment: I would say you are running your timer too frequently - every 100ms even though you only display second-level accuracy. Do you really need to do those calculations 10 times a second, only for the string to stay the same?

Comment: The stack trace seems normal, can you post the log when your app crashes?

Comment: @Homosapiens Logcat ouptputs has been added sorry.. for the late

Comment: @KenWolf I put it 1000 milliseconds and the activity closed after 3 minutes of playing that track

Comment: @YahiaSweid well it's an improvement :)

Comment: @KenWolf but it's not solution maybe i wanna play Qura'n .. there are tracks has 1 hour of length ! how can i do that ?

Comment: You need to investigate your `millisecondsToTimer` method, I guess this is causing problems. Why do you keep calculating and setting the end time? mp.duration never changes, you don't need to set it every 100 ms, etc. etc. Experiment with that method. It's difficult to say as the logs don't appear to be useful.

Comment: @KenWolf I tried that without 'millisecondsToTimer' method, I put mp.getDuration() and mp.getCurrentPosition() methods and same problem that i have it will appear .. I told you before It doesn't matter..thx

Comment: @KenWolf I did it without any calculation and there's no progress :(
'endTime.setText(String.valueOf(mp.getDuration()));
 currentTime.setText(String.valueOf(mp.getCurrentPosition()));'